# How to sent @Version annotation field to JSON?

Tags: spring, jpa, jackson

How to sent @Version annotation field to JSON?

I have super class with version field:

```
@Version
@Column(name = "version", nullable = false)
private Long version;
```

And child class Project.

Project entity has this JSON data:

```
{
  "number": "123",
  "name": "Project 4"
}
```

And E-tag header (from version field):

```
ETag → "8"
```

How to add version field to JSON response?

Comment: and what has this problem to do with JPA API? You presumably retrieve your objects with JPA and they have the version set, and so it is simply down to your conversion of those POJOs to JSON ... which is absolutely nothing to do with JPA, or JPA annotations

Comment: In addition it is also not quite clear how this relates to JSON handling, since information on actual POJO is missing...